# System.DateTime and Sql datetime2 in Linq2Sql (using sqlmetal)

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, datetime, types, sqlmetal

I'd like to utilize new Sql `datetime2` data type for event logging (as standard datetime has lower precision than `System.DateTime` causing data loss on storing) but when i generate the code with `sqlmetal.exe` i get the following warning:

> db.dbml(98) : Warning DBML1008:
>   Mapping between DbType 'DateTime2(7)
>   NOT NULL' and Type 'System.DateTime'
>   in Column 'CreatedOn' of Type 'Event'
>   may cause data loss when loading from
>   the database.

The warning disappears if i change my column definition to `datetime2(2)` but 2 digits precision is lower than `System.DateTime` can handle, right? Why? How can i suppress the warning?

Comment: do you have .net framework 3.5 SP1 installed?

Comment: i do. but by primary target is .net4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might just ignore that warning. I've checked the source of sqlmetal (using Reflector) and found this:

```
case SqlDbType.DateTime2:
if (scale <= 2)
  return Compatibility.Compatible;
else
  return Compatibility.DataLossFromDatabase;
```

However, querying a datetime2 field from a sample database returned the whole 7 digit precision.

Comment: Is there a way to suppress it?

Comment: I don't see any ways to suppress it (at least not in the current version, 3.5.30729.1)

Answer (score 1):

SQLMetal is just a tool to generate your dbml file so it has no effect on runtime behaviour. But as a generation tool it may not be aware of the new datatype.

Have you tried editing the DBML yourself using an XML editor to see if you lose precision?